# get and set boolean type from database android sqlite

Tags: android, xml, database, sqlite, boolean

I'm new to android development so I don't have much idea to how can handle this problem.
I have a problem with extract part in my codes, I want to get all rows of my table but here is some problem with boolean type

```
public ArrayList<UserMealUnit> getUserMealUnit() {

    ArrayList<UserMealUnit> result = null;
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        myDataBase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = myDataBase.query(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT, new String[] { "*" }, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = new ArrayList<UserMealUnit>();
            do {
                result.add(extractUserMealUnit(cursor));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    return result;      
}

//extract

private UserMealUnit extractUserMealUnit(Cursor cursor) {
    UserMealUnit usermealunit = new UserMealUnit();
    boolean value1;
    usermealunit.setMealid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_ID)));
    usermealunit.setBreakfast(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST)));
    return usermealunit;
}
```

breakfast type is boolean but `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST)` return int and here is the problem. I search about this problem but cant find anything useful. can any one help me?

Comment: Android development use SQL database. Check this for more info. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no boolean type in SQLite database. Instead, you must save 0 as false and 1 as true. Thus to read your value

```
final boolean breakfast = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST) != 0;
```

When using the ContentValues the system will convert the `Boolean` into `int` for you automatically when saving.

```
contentValues.put(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST, booleanValue);
```

Comment: Doctoror Drive I used class model 
`public class UserMealUnit {
 int mealid;
 boolean breakfast;}
 public boolean isBreakfast() {
  return breakfast;
 }
 public void setBreakfast(boolean breakfast) {
  this.breakfast = breakfast;
 }
`
and also in my databaseadapter
`ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST, usermealunit.isBreakfast());`
also use your answer
but still have problem.

Comment: @mimi put it in a setter then. `usermealunit.setBreakfast(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_USERMEALUNIT_BREAKFAST)) != 0);`